# How to combine ggplot with chartSeries

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantmod

Let's take some artificial plot created by `ggplot` :

```
ggplot()+aes(x  = 1:100, y = 1:100) + geom_line()
```

[image]

And also let's consider candlestick plot created by `chartSeries` :

```
start <- as.Date("2013-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2016-10-01")
# Apple stock
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
chartSeries(AAPL)
```

[image]

My question is : How can I plot them side-by-side - something what function `plot_grid()` from `cowplot` package does for `ggplot` objects. I checked and `plot_grid()` will not work to plot them side-by-side due to fact that `chartSeries` is not a `ggplot` object. So is there any way how can I plot both them next to each other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `chartSeries` is a chob. This can not be transformed by cowplot to a grob.

To get what you want you could use the functions from tidyquant. This returns the stockdata as a `tibble` / `data.frame` and it has some functions to plot everything in ggplot2. See [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyquant/vignettes/TQ04-charting-with-tidyquant.html) for more options. Then you can combine everything with the cowplot or patchwork package. I only show the result from patchwork. But the cowplot looks the same minus the title and captions.

```
library(tidyquant)
library(ggplot2)
aapl <- tq_get("AAPL", from = start, to = end)
aapl_plot <- aapl %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = close)) + 
  geom_candlestick(aes(open = open, high = high, low = low, close = close))


g <- ggplot() +aes(x = 1:100, y = 1:100) + geom_line() 

#combine with cowplot
cowplot::plot_grid(g, aapl_plot)

# combine with patchwork
library(patchwork)
g + aapl_plot + plot_annotation('This is a title', caption = 'made with patchwork')
```

[image]